# Silverlight with XNA vs purely HTML5

Tags: c#, c++, silverlight, html, windows-phone-7

I recently decided to go into WP7 app development, but haven't actually started learning silverlight/xna; Only C#. I already know C++ quite well.

my Dad, who works for Microsoft, has recently told me that there's no point to learning Silverlight because it will become irrelevant in the long run; due to HTML5's superiority. However, Im not aware of any way to develop apps for WP7 using HTML5, and I barely know anything about markup languagez anyway.

I wanted to get some proffesional advice on this, so here's my question:

**Taking my C++ backround into account, what would the pros/cons of the HTML5 path and the WP7/silverlight/xna path?** In terms of financials (cost of WP7 app submition, website hosting, etc), familiorarity (C++), and flexability (abilities of language)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now there is only one way to develop good apps in term of UX and OS services - Silverlight/XNA (not only first or second, but you can combine these two in a one app). Later MS will add support for C++, hence you are C++ dev the best option is to pick up C# and start making apps.

Regarding this "Silverlight is dead long live...eee HTML 5?". We all have heard that there is a new thing that solves all the problems and would be great - all of them failed, badly. Sure, it has it place, but mobile HTML5 apps suck in comparison with native apps. They're slow, use a lot of resources. Moore's law exponent is slowing down, size of a phone is limited and batteries capacity doubles every ...40 years. Cannot put a lot more silicon, make transistors many times smaller, this is not the best scenario for HTML where you have to download it, parse it and then download css, javascript, pictures etc. while users want their phones to be fast and fluid. One trick pony does one trick.

Maybe there will be some form of compilation to Binary HTML/bytecode, yet right now I don't believe ya.

Comment: +1 for "HTML5 solves all problems". The whole comparison is flawed, but people seem to easily agree without even trying EITHER for themselves. I remember that game Lemmings, It was a cool game...

Answer (score 3):

The Silverlight/XNA route feels 100% natural for me as a Developer. I started building an WP7 app about 2 weeks ago and completely I'm blown away by how productive C# / Silverlight has allowed me to be. That is, with ZERO previous experience in Silverlight/WPF... Just my general .NET/C# knowledge.

Silverlight might be going away from the Browser, but I think it has a very bright future on Windows Phone and Windows 8.

I found this book extremely helpful: http://www.gottabemobile.com/2010/11/04/101-windows-phone-7-apps-the-book/

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Ellery! Have you ever used HTML5? do I even need to know much silverlight to make a nice quality app or just xna?

Comment: As lukas says below, HTML5 is still very limited for mobile apps. I'm mainly a "backend" developer, so I'm more comfortable with C# than I am with Javascript. Follow some online tutorials for WP development and you'll pick up on Silverlight quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You could look in to [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) for building native WP7 apps from HTML5.

Comment: PhoneGap uses HTML5, not the native platform APIs directly.

Comment: @Paul at least they say PhoneGap is an HTML5 app platform that allows you to author native applications with web technologies and get access to APIs and app stores.