# Android, iPhone, iPad, Windows Phone recurring (subscription) payments for Fitness app

Tags: android, iphone, ios, windows-phone-7, mobile

I was wondering if anyone has any experience selling apps through the Android, iPhone and Windows Phone market places using a subscription (recurring) payment model?

I have the requirement to develop a [cross platform WP7, iPhone, Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755801/anyone-have-experience-with-architecture-for-cross-platform-wp7-android-ios-mobi) for a health and fitness company. The company wishes to sell the app as a monthly subscription, rather like you would a gym membership. It will be delivering personalised workout and nutrition advice to users as they progress through the programme.

I've read that iPhone supports directly a subscription model for content-delivery apps, e.g. newsreaders, that android supports in-app payments however Windows Phone doesn't seem to support anything like this. So, my question is:

1. Is something like recurring payments natively supported by any or all of the three main marketplaces?
2. If not, is there a workaround? Like prompting the user to renew monthly or quarterly and processing a new payment? Any comments / suggestions welcome.
3. Finally, what caveats should I be aware of with the three main marketplace hosts? I've heard horror stories of companies blacklisted for processing payments outside of the marketplace agreements.

---

The Windows Phone application policy states

> Your application must be fully functional when acquired from Windows
>   Phone Marketplace (except for additional data as permitted below).
>   Unless you have a pre-existing billing relationship with the user,
>   your application may not require the user to provide payment
>   information, within the application experience, to activate, unlock,
>   or extend usage of the application.

However this paragraph seems to be [ambigious](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/88256.aspx). If anyone has any further information on this specifically I would appreciate it!

---

Finally, I have found some third party payment processors which claim to allow subscription payments through cloud services, e.g.

- [MoVend](https://www.movend.com/)
- [Linxster](http://linxter.com/)

Again appreciate anyone who has had experience with using a similar method to achieve a subscription or recurring payment, even one driven by the user.

Best regards,

Comment: I can't provide any sources for this, but Android market supports in-app payments, but not recurring ones and Appstore does support recurring in-app payments.

Comment: Android IAB: http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html

Comment: Ok that's good, but does Windows-Phone have a similar model?

Comment: Windows Phone has no In app payment support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As told by a Microsoft rep yesterday:
The only way to do this on Windows Phone will be to redirect the user to a website and take the payment there. It's not permitted to take payment details directly within an app.

Comment: But its legit to do so. If so, great! As it happens reviewing the market it seems a common model to monetize apps like this is have free and pro, with pro costing around £3 for one off downloads. Then using the volume of users of free to deliver parter ads or redirect traffic to a web store with merchandise. Seems value is skewed on the marketplace - a product which could reasonably cost £50 on the web is £3 on mobile!

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson pricing of any product is a complicated process filled with nuances. It's furtherr complicated on mobile as there is a large expectancy that devices will be free and many developers want to compete on price and yet still hope to make a fortune.