# Any well know/productivity Apps using Monotouch/Monodroid

Tags: android, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

My company is evaluating an cross platform solution in mobile development area. 
Monotouch/Monodroid looks like very promise in some way.

And my boss is very interesting about any well know/productivity Apps using Mono mobile?

I found 3 Apps:

1. http://icircuitapp.com/ 
   from http://blog.xamarin.com/2011/10/26/java-to-ipad-in-2-months/
2. http://mobilebits.de/Blog/post/2011/01/05/Delayed-blogging-of-building-the-first-SoulCraft-Tech-Demo-version.aspx
   from http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/01/MonoDroid
3. http://www.apple.com/ipad/business/profiles/medtronic/
   from [Anyone have experience with architecture for cross platform WP7 Android iOS mobile development (monotouch, monodroid, C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755801/anyone-have-experience-with-architecture-for-cross-platform-wp7-android-ios-mobi)

Anyone know famous Apps using that technical ?

This is a bad question.

I see duplicated questions in stackoverflow. None give answers.

Anyway, I pretty sure people interested in Monotouch/Monodroid has same question as mine, 
it's real important to convince team to believe this solution.

Comment: FYI: google translate + multiquestion = closed within 5mins

Comment: Our app has been on the top 10 this week: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/draw-a-stickman-episode-2/id505295789?ls=1&mt=8  It uses MonoTouch, and a UIWebView with HTML5/Javascript (we did this b/c we needed to run a web app as an app).  We do other "businessy" apps with MonoTouch, it works great.  Can't imagine doing what we would need to do in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

Well-known is relative. OTOH you can browse Xamarin's [app showcase](http://xamarin.com/apps) to see **some** of the application that has been developed using MonoTouch and Mono for Android that were submitted back to us (I work for Xamarin) to be part of the showcase.

Note that this is not a question that fits stackoverflow goals (it's not about programming - but the applications). Consider sending an email to support@xamarin.com if you have similar questions.

Comment: yep, i already study Xamarin's showcase and this site http://monotouch.info/MonoTouch/Apps, i want more "well-known" cases, thx:)